# R gWidgets2 Get Row Number of Widget

Tags: r, user-interface, gwidgets

I'm using the glayout object in gWidgets2 to create a number of rows with some objects in them. I want the user to be able to add a new row anywhere in the table. I have a button at the end of each row that calls a function to add the new row directly above the current one.

My problem is that I'm using a loop to create my rows and I'm not sure how to pass the current row number to the event handler.  The code below passes my loop index, 'i', in the event handler, but I know that is wrong.

Is there a way for me to pass the current row number? I know I can change the entire layout so that the user inputs the index they'd like to add a row after, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it like this.

Here is an excerpt from the 'wrong' code:

```
for (i in 1:nrows){
    r_tbl[i+1,1] <- glabel(i)
    r_tbl[i+1,2] <- gspinbutton(from=0, to=990, by=10, expand=TRUE)
    r_tbl[i+1,3] <- gspinbutton(from=9, to=999, by=10, expand=TRUE)
    r_tbl[i+1,6] <- gbutton('Add Bin', handler=function(h,...){add(i+1)})
}
```

Comment: You can pass in `i` through the action argument, though you may need to force it's value as otherwise lazy evaluation might catch you. But I don't think you will have much success inserting rows between two existing rows -- unless you build in space on construction -- though you should be able to append rows.

Comment: Thanks, I will see what I can do with the action argument. Before I read your comment I was able to get it working by using tag and referencing tag(h$obj) inside the handler.

Comment: Yes, that will work. But I think tag was deprecated in gwidgets2.